# POINTER value in hexadecimal number system

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ in the Codeblocks environment.

I am not getting pointer value as a decimal number (variable is a pointer to an integer) even after applying

```
>>cout.setf(ios::dec);
```

It's displayed as a hexadecimal, but I want it to be a decimal number.  What should I do?  (I'm using c++ for dummies to learn)

Comment: Have you tried casting: `cout << ((unsigned int) my_pointer) << "\n";`?

Comment: A pointer is NOT an integer.  (well it might fit one, but that's besides the point)  It's a pointer TO an integer.  Most likely what you're seeing is the memory address, which is (usually) in hex.  Most likely you'll need to dereference the pointer to get the value of the integer.

Comment: Could you add a short example, about 5 lines, which show how you initialize your pointer and then do the actual printing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ios::dec` only applies to integer types. A pointer is not an integer even though it's converted to one for printing. After the conversion, pointers are always printed in hexadecimal base.

If you want to print the value of the pointer's representation in decimal base, you must first convert it to an integer and pass the integer to the stream. You can use `reinterpret_cast` to do the conversion.

"Which integer type should I convert a pointer to?" you might ask. Well, `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer type guaranteed to be big enough to represent a pointer without overflow. Use that.

---

Comments on your attempt:

```
int a=5;
int b = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a);
        ^                 ^
        dereference       a pointer type
```

What I suggested you to do is to cast the the pointer to an integer type. What you tried to do is cast it to a pointer type. `int*` is a pointer to `int`. The type of `&a` is already `int*`. Casting `int*` to `int*` is pointless. Here is how you can cast a pointer to an integer:

```
reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&a);
```

Another problem in your attempt is that you dereference the pointer. That's what you should do when you want to get the *pointed* value. The pointed value is obviously `5`. But if you want the address of the value i.e. the value of the pointer, then you don't dereference the pointer.

Comment: okay ,suppose, (int a=2; int* b=&a;).can you please tell me the how can i express 'b' with "reinterpret_cast"  so that after i run it i see 'b ' is coming in decimal number system!!

Comment: @subh did you look up how `reinterpret_cast` is used? Did you try it but it didn't work? Show me what you tried and I'll tell you what went wrong.

Comment: It's obvius I have made mistake!but what to add to make it coming in binary decimal system of value 'b' here.double a=5.654;
     int* b=reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a);

     cout<<"the addres is:"<<b;

Answer (score 0):

Looking from the other perspective, We can also say that the only way to store a hexadecimal value in C/C++ is using a pointer variable. Otherwise, it can't be done directly.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than a proper answer...